# Value cannot be empty. Parameter name: userName

Tags: 2011, 2013, core-service, cme

I am getting this error while logging with CME.

This is the complete error message:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault]: Value cannot be empty. Parameter name: userName. (Fault Detail is equal to Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault).

What does this error mean?

Comment: Have you checked if the Tridion Content Manager Service Host is running?  Have you tried restarting it?

Comment: yes after making changes i restarted my iis and services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a IIS issue we have to set Deny Rule For Local User..
Refer Link

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772441(v=ws.10).aspx